# Custom Drawable As CardView Background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make the following screen. I am using `CardView` and I am facing difficulty in creating custom `CardView`. Following is the image:

[Thank you Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trgPQ.png)

I have used the following code. This is what I have tried so far.

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/micro_xml"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card6Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Daily Check In"
                    android:textColor="#080808"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card6Description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Just Check in Daily and Earn Credits"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="12dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card6Image"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If the above-given code isn't good enough for this to be achieved, I think I should:
Use an image as a background to `CardView` which already has this thumb and shape.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using custom AlertDialog.

Sorry, I can't provide you code snippet right now just the way you need (cause I don't have access to IDE atm). But the idea is to use a Relative layout to design the way you want your dialog to be. Use imageview with shape drawable to make it round shape and place that relative to the Textviews.

Set the layout as the view for your alertdialog.

Before you call `.show()` on your alertdialog, use

```
"alertdialog".getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

//replace the "alertdialog" with your alerdialog name.//
```

This would make the background of the dialog transparent and only the parts you want to show can be seen.

Answer (score -1):

AFIK, you could not create this kind of layout using `CardView`. You could try to use the custom layout and set the `android:elevation` parameter.